# Jquery EasyTabs Plugin not working...not sure why

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to use a jquery plugin called [Easy Tabs](http://os.alfajango.com/easytabs/) with very little success.

Full disclosure: I'm new to jquery/javascript but I followed the instructions on the developer's website as much as humanly possible.

Here's what I have in the top of my file:

```
 <head>
    <link href="Resources/Stylesheets/PWS_template.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="/Resources/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <script src="/Resources/js/jquery.hashchange.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <script src="/Resources/js/jquery.easytabs.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <script src="/Resources/js/jquery.hashchange.min.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready( function() {
        $('#tab-container').easytabs();
        </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 >tab_test</h1>
    <div id="tab-container" class="tab-container">
        <ul class="etabs">
            <li class="tab"><a href="#tab1">HTML Markup</a>
            </li>
            <li class="tab"><a href="#tab2">Required JS</a>
            </li>
            <li class="tab"><a href="#tab3">Example CSS</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

I know the CSS is working since I can see the tab content looking like tabs...but nothing. else. works.

I just don't know where to go from here (or what other info to include here).

Does anyone see anything wrong with what I've included? The screenshot shows exactly what I see when I run the page in Mozilla. If I click on a tab, the URL changes - but that's it.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Laura

Answer (score 0):

Your $(document).ready is not closed in the script.
It should look like this:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function() {
      $('#tab-container').easytabs();
    });
  </script>
```

Also make sure you are in the working directory. Add a "."  in the src
It should look like this:

```
<link href="Resources/Stylesheets/PWS_template.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="./Resources/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <script src="./Resources/js/jquery.hashchange.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <script src="./Resources/js/jquery.easytabs.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <script src="./Resources/js/jquery.hashchange.min.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
```

. = **This** Location

.. = **Up** a directory